# For which x does this series converge?

Tags: real-analysis

Assume $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R} $ is differentiable, $f(0)=0$ and $f’$ is bounded. For $x \in \mathbb{R}$ we define $\sum_{n \geq 1} f\left( \frac{x}{n^2}\right)$. For what $x$ does this series converge?


I have no clue how to solve this. I know that because $f$ is differentiable, it is continuous and because the derivative is bounded, it is even uniformly continuous. I know that the series converges for $x=0$ (or any $x$ for which $f(x)=0$). I’m trying out various convergence tests, but I feel like there’s something I’m missing...

How do I use the uniform continuousness?

Comment: **Hint :** $$f\left( \frac{x}{n^2}\right) \sim \dfrac{x}{n^2}f'(0)$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Lagrange's theorem and the boundedness of $f'$
$$|f(\frac{x}{n^2})|\leq C\frac{|x|}{n^2}$$
and so the series always (absolutely) converges